# PyQt5 app compiled with PyInstaller using --onefile and --noconsole, but exe fails to launch

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyinstaller, exe

Using Qt Designer and PyQt5, I have made a simple app that does some simple modifications on a .txt file and saves it. I successfully compiled my program using PyInstaller with the following command:

```
pyinstaller --distpath DESTINATION_PATH --onefile --noconsole myscript.py
```

The executable is created, but when I try to run it, I get an error saying that **the application failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect**.
If I do not use the --noconsole, the executable runs fine but this is not how I intend to run it.
I am fairly new to PyQt5 and PyInstaller, and I read somewhere that my program should not include "subprocesses" when using --noconsole but I am not entirely sure what that means.
If of any relevance, my antivirus was deleting the .exe when compiled with --onefile --noconsole but not when only using --onefile. However, this issue was soon solved by creating an exception.

Here are the imports I use:

```
import sys, re, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QFileDialog, QApplication, QMessageBox
from pathlib import Path
import pyperclip as pc
```

Comment: Try adding `pyperclip` as hidden import to spec file: `hiddenimports=['pyperclip']`

Comment: Alright, I will try doing that by Sunday. I am currently off and cannot access my desktop PC. Could you tell me whether I will need to copy the spec file with the program later on? Or is it necessary only on my PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided above by ThePyGuy has solved the issue. Adding `hiddenimports=['pyperclip']` in the spec file was enough to prevent the error from occuring and the program ran fine to the extent that I tested it.